# Add Scales in x and y coordinates in OpenCV in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am looking to add the scales in both axis in the following image using OpenCV, where scale tells how much distance is from some origin to x axis and y axis.

In matplotlib the coordinates are automatic, can we do samething in OpenCV?

P.S I searched a lot but none of the results I received is relevant.

[image: op]

Comment: [You'd have to draw your own with OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html) as its primarly an imaging library & not a data presentation library.

Comment: @DrBwts sure but I assumed that this task is quite common so there might be some implementation examples available

Comment: use matplotlib in addition to OpenCV. OpenCV has nothing that lets you do this trivially, besides the afore-mentioned drawing primitives (lines etc)

Comment: @user0193 this task is not that common enough in the broad image-processing community. Anyway, if you provide code with what you have so far, and an example of what you'd like it to look like, maybe you'll find some help here.

Comment: @Berriel I have a code which creates OpenCV image using python sci-kit library, now I want to add the x and y axis scales, so that it can measure the distance like the map above (which is an image overlayed onto the gaussian plot) I just want to show distance scale, just like google map provides so one can get an idea of the scaling of the map